# Linux partition system

Tags: partitioning, mount, ext4

While installing Ubuntu, I only created two partitions for Ubuntu one for swap and I formatted the other as ext4 and set mount point as "/". The Operating System is working flawlessly.

I was just reading a few Ubuntu install guides and found that most of them suggest creating more partitions and mount them as "/root", "/home", etc, etc.

Is there a difference between the two sorts of install methods?   Is there a performance difference between the two methods?

Comment: Note that `/root` is unsafe to put in a separate partition. You're probably thinking of the root (`/`) filesystem, which is the base for everything else. The `/root` directory is the `root` (administrative) user's home directory. This can be confusing, particularly when spoken, but it's important to understand the difference between root (`/`) and `/root`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a difference not so much for performance but for the easier administration.
The layout I usually use for partitioning is:

```
/
/var
/home
/tmp
swap partition.
```

I setup /var and /tmp on different mount points in order to keep the root filesystem / clean because /var can get filled by downloaded updates and /tmp can get filled with temporary files and thus causing the system not to run properly.

Also i keep /home on a separate partition because in case of a reinstall I can keep all the personal settings there and after the system is reinstalled the applications can read the settings from there, otherwise you need to backup the data and restore it after reinstall

Comment: This answer is good, but note that partitioning choices are matters of both system-specific needs and personal preference. It's therefore impossible to give advice on this score without knowing a lot about how the computer is to be used -- probably more than most newbies know themselves. Thus, defaults tend to be simple configurations like a root (`/`)/swap split, or those two plus `/home`.